# Data tables copy,save only selected rows on individual multi filter select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am trying to copy the selected rows in the table, when I click the buttons for copy,csv, excel, print the entire table copying and downloading.

How to get the selected rows in the table, and copied to clipboard, save as the file.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
         "dom": 'T<"clear"><"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
        "tableTools": {
"sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
        initComplete: function () {
            var api = this.api();

            api.columns().indexes().flatten().each( function ( i ) {
                var column = api.column( i );
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );

      $('#submitFrm').click( function() {
        var data = table.$('input, select').serialize();
        alert(
            "The following data would have been submitted to the server: \n\n"+
            data.substr( 0, 120 )+'...'
        );
        return false;
    } );
} );
```

With copy, save, print, buttons and also the individual filter on the column.But the thing is selected rows are not copying in the clipboard and csv after downloading showing entire data not selected rows.

How to copy,csv .. only the selected rows in the table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/dbecbww1/

```
   just an example. for additional questions, you might need to 
post again another question.
    check if it is also working for your buttons, if not, 
configure your datatableTools.tableTools.js 
function "_fnGetDataTablesData", try to debug.
 I've tried manipulating it before.
```

FYI: 
you can set which columns you only need to copy for your files.

NOTE: set your swf path normally, which I think you have done already. the swf path for the fiddle is not working so the buttons won't work. I've been searching for working swf paths online but to no avail. Mine works perfectly fine in my local project, though.

Comment: Nope,  I configure datatablesTools.tableTools.js ..and swf path is set  in localhost and  copy of the selected rows are not working and in the <tfoot>  the data is not populating ....please check

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle? when you click the submit button, it serializes the selected rows only. Same will happen with the buttons. What's your configuration for the _fnGetDataTablesData?